# Is it possible to use OR condition in search_api_index view for exposed filters like "Fulltext search" or "Combine fields filter"

Tags: search, 9

I have created search_api_index view.

And I want to add filter criteria like on screenshot.
[image]

or

[image]

I choose OR condition, but the AND condition still works. It seems that OR condition is not applied. Is it possible to implement such behavior?

Expected result should looks like on the screenshot with OR condition
[image]

Comment: Should they be two condition groups with title in one and fulltext search in the other?

Comment: @Kevin i have updated my question.

Comment: Yes, did you try adding a new "Condition Group" in Views and splitting the fields between them? Is it also possible the fulltext search and title both provide hits?